# PnP JS Person field only returns FieldId and FieldStringId

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, pnp, pnpjs

I have a list with a few columns that are Person columns. Below is a snippet without a select nor expand:

```
const newHires = this._sp.web.lists.getById(`${listId}`).items<ListItem[]>();
const resolvedTasks = Promise.resolve(newHires);
```

Two of my Person fields are called Manager and Dude. As you'll see from the screenshot, I only get DudeId and DudeStringId (ditto for Manager field).

When I try the following:

```
        const newHires = this._sp.web.lists.getById(`${listId}`).items.select("Manager/Email").expand("Manager")<ListItem[]>();
```

I get the following 400 error:

> "odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The query to field 'Manager' is not valid. The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains Manager."

I've also checked in the library settings that the field name is indeed Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using endpoint like:

```
const newHires = this._sp.web.lists.getById(`${listId}`).items.select("Manager/EMail").expand("Manager")<ListItem[]>();
```

Use `EMail` instead of `Email`.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!